# How to fix Android Emulator internal error : emuglConfig_init : blacklisted=0 has_guest_renderer=1

Tags: android

Im' trying to launch android emulator but this error appear after launching. I'have a AMD Ryzen processor. I follow these steps :

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html

I ever try to change the windows power options but without success and I also try to change emulated performence to Software GLES 2.0.

[image: error]

Have you idea ?

Comment: Were you able to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I changed the android version back to 9 (Pie). Found it [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1454499/android-emulator-closed-because-internal-error-emuglconfig-init-blacklisted-0?rq=1).